# Coreml EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7d66228) Error on WatchOs

Tags: swift, watchos, coreml, watchos-5

I have a coreml model created with Create ML. The model works on iPhone Simulator. However it doesn't work on watch simulator. What may be the problem? It gives the following error:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7d66228) expression produced error:
>   error:
>   /var/folders/zb/dn1s2sqj66789g1ht_cz3glh0000gn/T/expr1-5fb02f..swift:1:65:
>   error: use of undeclared type 'CoreML'
>   Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer(bitPattern:
>   0x1932c0)!.pointee)

this error is related to below auto generated function.

```
func prediction(input: HandWashInput, options: MLPredictionOptions) throws -> HandWashOutput {
    let outFeatures = try model.prediction(from: input, options:options)
    return HandWashOutput(features: outFeatures)
}
```

Simulator: watch 5 series
XCode: 11.4
Swift version: 5

[image]

Comment: I tried Create ML by using Support Vector Machine and doing binary classification and it worked. However it doesn't work with multi-class classifications. Strange.

Comment: Update: The problem should be related to watchOS simulator. There must be a bug. I tried on real series 5 watch and it works perfectly for both binary and multi-class classification.